# Feature request for uploading small-sized sound and movie file, and SVG format still image files

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I keep a request for uploading sound files (wma, amr, mp3, midi etc). animation-file in gif format is being already allowed (and helpful) , but some-other sorts of video files (video recording files) such as mp4, AVI, 3gp, etc. within a strict limit of file-size and time.

At the same-time,  amazingly small SVG files (for still-image quite like png-s and gif-s) from wikipedia, could not be directly used here. If the spectrum of allowed formats for still-images slightly broadened, this website will basically be benefited.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103850/allow-sound-file-uploads-in-questions-and-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75608/is-there-any-way-i-could-embed-a-video-in-my-question

Comment: We this need to upload recordings of coil whine and then have some veteran EE tell us how many henry the inductors have based on the recording.

Comment: Old request for SVG files on meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is done, please **do not have the files play automatically** when the web page is loaded.  Moving images are distracting when you're trying to read text, and having sound coming out of your speakers without your permission is very annoying, rude to others, and possibly against the rules in a office environment.

Another reason to make sound and moving pictures not play automatically is that most of the time I won't want to see them, and even less hear them.  Perhaps there are a few cases where animation or sound would really add useful information to a question that would be difficult to convey otherwise, but most of the time people are going to use it as a crutch in place of actually thinking about the problem and writing a proper description.  I can promise that such uses are going to get downvoted fast, and closed with little thought for the nearest handy reason.

Comment: Autoplay features are really irritating. I absolutely agree. however a very-short, technical file (say the sounds originated from an analog radio or loudspeaker in presence of nearby mobile phone activities) etc. will greatly help in understanding to the future users.

Answer (score 7):

I'm curious how often you anticipate this being used, and for what purpose. More than 9 times out of 10, a video in a question does nothing to clarify the answer, and (personally) I won't watch it anyway: I'd rather spend one minute reading a clearly written answer than waste several minutes watching a poorly lit, shaky video.

There are so few instances in which a video or sound byte is really *essential* to a post, that simply linking to an external video or audio host (of which there are many) seems completely sufficient.

Finally, as Olin mentioned, adding such functionality would only encourage the unnecessary use of such media, leading to even more low-effort questions.

Comment: Indeed, videos are *terrible*. You waste your time waiting for the interesting moment, which doesn't come, so you move the cursor 3min later, of course it's too late, must re-watch... The worse being video tutorials that last 10min to show something explainable in two sentences. If there are ever questions with videos here, no way I watch them and answer.